# set up socat for USB port as TCP biderctional communication

Tags: java, linux, tcp, socat

I have this serial port Sensor I would like to connect to via TCP .
can anyone share socat setup for this kind of connection?

my serial port needs:

- USB -> /dev/ttyUSB0
- BAUDRATE 9600
- DATABITS 8
- STOPBITS 1
- PARITY 0 /NONE

I can read and write to the posrt using minicom but I would like to automate this using java so I need an TCP client for the task to work.

Be able to write and read results form the port.

Thanks.

here is an example that doesnt work:

```
socat -d -d -d -d -x TCP-LISTEN:7757,reuseaddr,fork FILE:/dev/ttyUSB0,b9600,raw
```

Comment: why do you say it does not work ?

Comment: If you look at my answer below you see I was missing some options. This is for a very specific sensor type. Are you using the same sensor?

Answer (score 0):

here is my bash script for debug

```
#!/bin/bash
# socat start script

socat -d -d -d -d tcp-listen:4141,reuseaddr,fork file:/dev/ttyUSB0,nonblock,cs8,b9600,cstopb=0,raw,echo=0
```

Remove the '-d' to remove debug

This fits a specific type of sensors connected via USB